# make new column using value_counts in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i am using below formula to get value count froma. column in  a dataframe:

```
new_data = df['item'].value_counts()
```

which give me below result

```
Apples                    3
Green bananas             2
Bananas                   1
Oranges                   1
```

what i want is to get output for every item count in in new column like the below excel example

[image: example]

Any help or guidance is appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for your solution:

```
new_data = df['item'].value_counts()
df['Occurence'] = df['item'].map(new_data)
```

One row solution:

```
df['Occurence'] = df['item'].map(df['item'].value_counts())
```

If there is multiple columns:

```
cols = ['item','item1']
for c in cols:
    df[f'Occurence_{c}'] = df[c].map(df[c].value_counts())

 df.loc[len(df), cols] = df[cols].sum()
```

Or:

```
df = df.join(df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts())).add_prefix('Occurence_'))
```

Comment: i have more then one column to do the same thing with different item headers how can i do it?

Comment: @Zac - Do you think `df['Occurence1'] = df['item1'].map(df['item1'].value_counts())` ?

Comment: okday so i have to do same code for every column

Comment: Thank you so much,now last question. How can i sum every row cols occurance and total it in new column

Comment: @Zac - You can add ` df.loc[len(df), cols] = df[cols].sum()`, added to answer.

Comment: i want sum of all new columns occurence_{c} in new column called total

Comment: @Zac - Then use `df['Total'] = df.filter(like='occurence_').sum(axis=1)`

Answer (score 2):

Try with `transform`

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('item')['item'].transform('count')
```

Answer (score 1):

Or by the index:

```
df.set_index('item').assign(count=df['item'].value_counts()).reset_index()
```

Since column assigning corresponds to the index, this way would do it.